# Flow To POST Direct Link of Image to HTTP Endpoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-flow

I am having some issues with image sharing in SharePoint when using flows.

My end goal is to have the flow:

1. Trigger when a file is uploaded
2. Make a HTTP POST request to an endpoint with a direct link to the image.

I have it all working but my issue is getting the direct link to the image. Using the following action creates a shareable link, but it is not a direct link to the image itself:

[image: Sharepoint sharing link]

Comment: Did you try with Get File Content step?

Answer (score 0):

Use the **link to item** output from trigger:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately the link isn't accessible to outside users.

Comment: Is there any error message?

Comment: Just that the URL requires a login before accessing the content itself.